# Sublime Text 4 autocomplete when word includes period/dot "."

Tags: r, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublimetext4

In R code "." can be part of a variable name and at least in my and others' experience period is used as a separator for long variable names. In ST3 autocomplete worked fine when I had names such as "first.dataframe". So when I typed "first", "first.dataframe" appeared in the autocomplete options.

Now in ST4 this doesn't work anymore, and you only get suggested "first". This issue has been reported several months ago but developers don't think this is a priority. This is a dealbraker for me so I am looking for a solution otherwise I will switch to a different editor.

Is it possible to modify this behaviour through some internal custom routine, a package, or by modifying syntax recognition options?

Comment: Have you tried editing the `"word_separators"` setting to remove `.`?

Comment: @MattDMo I did but it doesn't work, it's a known bug.